# Command not working after adding embed fields and thumbnails

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm currently making my help command more fancy. I added fields for the embed and a thumbnail. Whenever I run the bot and try the command, it does not send anything. I looked over and over again and can't find where the error is. No errors. Any clue where the problem is? Thanks!

```
@bot.command(aliases=['bothelp'])
async def help(ctx):
 embed=discord.Embed(title="Ultimate Bot Help", description="Hello! Here, you can get help from lots of useful links and info!", color=0x00FFFF)
 embed.add_field(name="Website", value="link here", incline=False)
 embed.add_field(name="Bot Suggestions", value="link here", incline=False)
 embed.add_field(name="Bot Invite", value="link here", incline=False)
 embed.add_field(name="Bot Prefix", value="My prefix is `>`")
 embed.set_thumbnail(url="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTnRvkNUAgzhNyYU_zWiyh0TNxzAQ0kWGZbHCrd5o8op9p9PUzSe_H4kiO-DxmnJ_lF9_sVi3ZEjHyUQC0n:https://cmkt-image-prd.freetls.fastly.net/0.1.0/ps/3277870/910/607/m1/fpnw/wm0/ghostplayer-logo-template-02-.png%3F1505882390%26s%3D930fa4a9fcbc678396da1bc42bcf862e&usqp=CAU")
 await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start off, the help command is already installed in the discord.py module. This would mean that the command would not work, so you need to disable it:

```
bot = commands.bot(command_prefix=“prefix”, help_command=None)
```

The second thing, is that for all of your embeds you are using the term `incline`, when the correct term is `inline`.